# in python after importing sys how can i import terminal

Tags: python, importerror

Python

```
import sys
from terminal import *
```

it says error: import "terminal" could not be resolved
I am new so I am probably doing something stupid here

I was just following a tutorial to make the game of life in terminal

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNsrHRJQdKo

Comment: You probably have not installed the terminal package in your python environment. So `pip install terminal` before you execute your file.

Comment: `terminal` is a third-party module.  You have to install it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The `sys` module ships standard with cPython.

In contrast the `terminal` module will need to be installed,
by following [these instructions](https://pypi.org/project/terminal).
The summary is:

```
$ pip install terminal
```

---

Here is an example.

```
$  python -c 'import terminal'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'terminal'
$
$  pip install terminal
Collecting terminal
  Downloading terminal-0.4.0.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: terminal
  Building wheel for terminal (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for terminal: filename=terminal-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl size=13146 sha256=b21c66c1df3d12257d260258496192e87e1ea9ffe6295543c045d9934ec60651
  Stored in directory: .../Library/Caches/pip/wheels/97/31/65/c0048996b231771b909f29274f054b1540fe0019960bed84d4
Successfully built terminal
Installing collected packages: terminal
Successfully installed terminal-0.4.0
$
$  python -c 'import terminal'
$
```

(Notice that now the `import` completes without reporting an error.)

Comment: hmm this not working for me so i will try some other means